# Elegant and pratical solution for retrieving full Namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces

This is being the bane of my project right now, and my past projects as well. For each of them I used options that were far from optimal.

The problem: My project has a registry that instantiates any class, requiring you to pass to it a fullnamespace, and retrieving that full namespace can be a pain. Example:

```
$registry->getClassInstance('\application\model\SomeModel');
```

To get that full namespace, I have a few options, all cumbersome:

1. Type SomeModel, and the PHP will find the namespace. However, its autocomplete will rather than print the fullnamespace, will print SomeModel() and add USE fullnamespace at the top of the file. If the IDE would simply print the fullnamespace where I was typing, this problem would have been resoveld. Instead, I have to right click on the autocomplete window twice to copy and paste the full namspace, then paste it myself and add a starting / to it, very cumbersome.
2. Use defined() constants for the namespaces. Double the work, half the performance, and can cause bugs with local CONSTS
3. Create a class object with functions to retrieve all namespaces. Again, a lot of trouble and unpractical to use

   How can I keep my namespace references easy to reach, and easy to update within a big project? How do big projects usually handle these?

Comment: I really hope someone can help me with this because I search a LOT for how to deal with includes and uses and requires in an organized way and I could never even find a discussion regarding this topic

Comment: This is so frustrating, why nobody ever talks about this? Everyone has tons of includes(path) or namespaces in their projects, yet I never see solutions on how to organize, retrieve and make them easy to update. What is a best practice for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don´t understand what are you asking for, or what do you really need.

I can suggest you, to take a look to the Symfony autoloader. You can use it as a component, without having to use the entire framework too.

Then, you can call classes, and add namespaces as if they were packages in Java.

That answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that isn't it. I already have an autoloader class. Let me try to put in a different way then. Throughout all my project, I will have many calls to the namespaces of my classes. If I have to change the namespace of a class, I have to find find all references to it in the code and fix, which is a bit error prone and time consuming to test. One way around this is to define() constants for the namespaces, but that introduces other issues mentioned on my original post. I'm trying to find a good practice on how to retrieve and store the namespace names

Comment: But, if you are working in Java, for example, and you change the name of a package, you also have to search through your code and fix (obviusly, the IDE, Netbeans or Eclipse make that for you, but it has to be done anyway...).